# Redirecting to mobile website using opencms

Tags: opencms

I have a website developed using OPENCMS. Now we have developed a mobile website. How do i add code or module to opencms so that when user visits from mobile, it will be redirected to mobile website.

Comment: This does not answer the question but might help:
http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Creating_Mobile_Templates_with_OpenCms_8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert at the beginning of one of the pages in the editor.

```
<?php 
    function detect_mobile()
        {
        if(preg_match('/(alcatel|amoi|android|avantgo|blackberry|benq|cell|cricket|docomo|elaine|htc|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipaq|ipod|j2me|java|midp|mini|mmp|mobi|motorola|nec-|nokia|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|sagem|sharp|sie-|smartphone|sony|symbian|t-mobile|telus|up\.browser|up\.link|vodafone|wap|webos|wireless|xda|xoom|zte)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
                return true;

            else
                return false;
        }

        $mobile = detect_mobile();

        if($mobile === true)


    header('Location: /mobile');
    ?>
```

Comment: yup its java based. SO i was wondering if there are already any modules for doing it in OpenCMS.

Comment: There are no modules out there for that, as it's almost just a one-liner actually, just as Scott sampled above. Just convert the logic to Java and place it in your main jsp template within OpenCms. That should be all. Either that (doing a header redirect), or if it's suitable for you, just include different css. I guess it really depends on each case.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var url=***'http://yourmobilesite.com/***';
var host_name=document.location.hostname;
var request_uri=document.location.pathname;
var no_mobile=location.search;
var cookie=document.cookie;

function detect()
{
  var ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  var devices=['vnd.wap.xhtml+xml','sony','symbian','nokia','samsung','mobile',
               'windows ce','epoc','opera mini','nitro','j2me','midp-','cldc-',
               'netfront','mot','up.browser','up.link','audiovox','blackberry',
               'ericsson','panasonic','philips','sanyo','sharp','sie-',
               'portalmmm','blazer','avantgo','danger','palm','series60',
               'palmsource','pocketpc','smartphone','rover','ipaq','au-mic',
               'alcatel','ericy','vodafone','wap1','wap2','teleca',
               'playstation','lge','lg-','iphone','android','htc','dream',
               'webos','bolt','nintendo'];
  for (var i in devices)
  {
    if (ua.indexOf(devices[i]) != -1)
    {
      return true
    }
  }
}

if (no_mobile!='?nomobile=1' && cookie.indexOf('no_mobile')==-1)
{
  is_mobile=detect();
  if (is_mobile)
  {
    window.location = url
  }
} 
else
{
  if (cookie.indexOf('no_mobile') != -1)
  {}
  else
  {
    cookie_expires = new Date();
    cookie_expires.setTime(cookie_expires.getTime()+60*60*24);
    document.cookie = "no_mobile=1; expires="
                      + cookie_expires.toGMTString()
                      + "; path=/;"
  }
}
</script>
```